# subscribe \ update subscriptions for tags by device\ userid in WL 7.1

Tags: push-notification, tags, ibm-mobilefirst, subscribe

We try to update "tags" for push notifications for any user\ device,
the only functions that we found is subscribe\ unsubscribe with alias **or** tags.
but if i need to update tags for some user how is the best way to do it?
user can be subscribed to lots of tags - this is the requirement (don't think that WL had problem with it)

tnx for your help,
sahar

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where do you need to update the tags? in the applications? its visual name? in the database? for a specific user? what is the nature of "updating a tag".

Comment: Adding new tags, or removing existing tags?

Comment: I want to update on WL DB that i can send push notifications by tags.

Comment: we need enable updates for users

Comment: Do you want to simply update user rows in the database with additional tags that the user did not originally subscribe to via the application interface?

Comment: 1. when the user update his tags so i want to updates his tags respectively on WL database (like i wrote - i cant find update function) 2. there are some user that are subscribe already with no tags (the logic is exist - but not subscribe correctly so i need to update his details with the new tags

Answer (score 0):

There is no API that allows you to manually 'update' the tag subscription.  You will have to call subscribeTag to add more tags to a specific device or unsubscribeTag to unsubscribe the device from the specific tag.  Tag subscriptions are tie to device registration, not user based.

Comment: Or, if I understand correctly, to simply run an SQL query to update the relevant database table rows with the required information.

Comment: if i will subscribe "again" with same tag and device id (i think these are the params the function need) what could happen?